# Fatal error: Call to undefined function expect_popen()

Tags: php, expect

Since my upgrade from PHP 5.5.9 to 5.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server I have been getting problems with the expect library for PHP. It keeps displaying the Fatal error in the description. I believe the package that I need for this is **libexpect-php5**. Some installation checks confirm that it is installed:

```
root@k1:/etc/php5/conf.d$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep expect
empty-expect                            install
expect                                  install
expect-dev                              install
expect-lite                             install
libexpect-ocaml                         install
libexpect-ocaml-dev                     install
libexpect-perl                          install
**libexpect-php5**                      install // installed right?
libexpect-simple-perl                   install
libghc-hspec-expectations-dev           install
libghc-hspec-expectations-doc           install
libghc-hspec-expectations-prof          install
libnet-scp-expect-perl                  install
libtest-expect-perl                     install
netexpect                               install
python-pexpect                          install
python-pexpect-doc                      install
python3-pexpect                         install
```

and

```
root@k1:/etc/php5/conf.d$ expect -v
expect version 5.45
```

and the expect.so files:

```
root@k1:/usr/lib$ ls | grep expect
libexpect.so
libexpect.so.5
libexpect.so.5.45
```

and finally my /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file:

```
extension=expect.so
```

I had to install libexpect-ph5 by downloading and installing the .deb file manually, because it was erring about an uninstallable dependency api... Now when I do and **apt-get update && apt-get upgrade** it keeps telling me this:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libexpect-php5
```

Just installing that package does something, but the system will still keep the package back. This leaves me with a PHP version that doesn't know about the expect_popen() function.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hi, Did you tried to restart the apache or server, to see if it takes the changes on the upgrade?

Comment: @JuanGarcia Yes, multiple times, but nothing changed ;-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that Apache2 was loading the wrong php.ini file. Since the upgrade to PHP 5.6 the path has changed as well (of course).

Old location:

```
/etc/php/apache2/php.ini
```

New location:

```
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
```

Along with that I had to specify the exact path to my expect.so extension in php.ini.

Comment: how did you install expect.so ?